# Drupal 7 - Use external database in (virtual?) nodes and views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, datasource, drupal-views, drupal-nodes

I'm a bit of a Drupal newbie but have committed myself to porting some quite complex bespoke websites.

One of these is a surf report site which uses a database with millions of time/location rows to get the local conditions. Obviously can't write this to a Drupal table everyday so am looking for a way to connect and retrieve live data.

I'll need to use the external data in a number of displays which would normally be nodes, views, blocks etc.

The ideal solution would be if the external data just appeared as local data, but I'm guessing that is a rather big ask.

I'm open to any approach. If it involves writing a module some pointers on what to look at (preferably code examples) would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [**Data** module](https://drupal.org/project/data).

From the [documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2180593):

> The Data module lets you use database tables that are foreign to Drupal.
>
> You can 'adopt' a table in your database that ordinarily Drupal would not be aware of. This might be external data you have imported, or a table that another application has created.

It also provides **Views** integration.

Comment: Thanks @unor. I did briefly look at the data module but didn't see this. I'll have another look. However, I managed to get views to recognise my database using the info here: http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/api-tables so may stick with this. I'm also thinking it may be easier to go down the writing a module route.

Answer (score 1):

I had to show info from a legacy staff databse in my Drupal 6. I have explored three ways:

1. Importing database rows as nodes in a nightly cronjob
2. Accessing the external database in my own module
3. Accessing the external database using [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7)

If I started again I would use [hook_views_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7), it's more flexible, specially if you want to match the external database information with drupal nodes.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module which can be used to display (= query, not update) data stored in databases external to Drupal. It comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections), such as MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, Postgres or any PDO compliant variation.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports) for an online example of the [Forena Documentation](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help).

The [Sample reports and graphs](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/samples) are fully functional, such as the drill downs available on the [Master Summary with drill down](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.state_summary). Using Forena "skins", you can also use the amazing "dataTables" (and its widgets, such as sorting by selected columns).

Forena also includes a UI for either creating your reports (the **WYSIWYG Report Editor**) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the **WYSIWYG Query Builder**).

<sup><sup>Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.</sup></sup>